# Dynamics 365 CE On-Premise Issue after Upgrade (2015 to 9.0) 'The 'RetrieveMultiple' method does not support entities for type 'xxx'

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I'm facing an issue with a MSD Upgrade 2015 to 365 9.0 On-Premise.

Below the steps I follow:
Upgrade 2015 to 2016 then 8.2 and then 9.0 (0.26)

When I tried to open the HomePageGrid for some entities I get this error:
The 'RetrieveMultiple' method does not support entities for type 'xxx'.
Also, not only RetrieveMultiple operation that doesn't work but all operations Create, Update.

I checked on the Database 9.0 and all entities that throw the error doesn't have a primary key defined. On Database 8.2 the primary key is set correctly

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Since you ask this on SO, how is this related to software development? Do you have any custom plugins in your solutions?

Comment: Altough I deactivated all plugin steps I have always the same problem. It's happening on some or almost all OOB entities. Even listing solution components is not working.

Comment: From what I remember, this was a MS bug - did you create a ticket with them. This will happen in UCI only not in classic right?

Comment: I didn't ceate a ticket yet. This happen in classic interface also. I added some updates to the post

Comment: have you found any solution for this ?
Exact same error here, for oob entities of sale, (from Opportunity to invoice)